# Bad Accuracy in Fused Location Api

Tags: android, gps, location, maps, android-fusedlocation

I'm trying to do a "tracking" app in Android. I'm using the Fused Location Api and, like in many different sites has been said, I'm filtering the locations by its accuracy.

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
  if (location.getAccuracy() <= 10.0f && location.hasAccuracy() ) {
    //saveLocation(); or whatever
   }
```

The code is more elaborated, it's only to reflect the idea.

The app draw a `Polyline` while i'm walking, and I got the location every 5 seconds. And if the GPS is not enabled I say the user to enable it.

The problem is (i'm not allowed to upload images so i'll describe it) that my path/route, the line, do weird curves, go inside buildings, etc...and I don't know how to just keep the line in the street...

If I change to the "old" API, with `locationManager` etc, I would receive better locations? Or there is another way with `Fused Location`?

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe if I just tqke the points every *more* seconds...the line will be straighter. (but if I change my direction it will go through buildings, too). I can't see  solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GPS signal is typically quite "noisy".  In my experience (mainly with location manager), even when the receiver is stationary, successive gps measurements can "jump" by as much as 10 m.  Connecting raw data points with polylines is likely to show a very jagged path.

My suggestion is to sample more rapidly and filter the data.  There are many ways to filter.  For example, you can simply average the most recent N latitude values (and do the same for the longitude) -- a "running average" filter.  A more sophisticated approach would use knowledge regarding likely speeds and changes in direction (e.g., Kalman filtering).

Comment: LocationManager with only GPS provider has great accuracy but FusedLocation API gives very bad accuracy often